# Position of tooltip in Tinymce

Tags: html, css, tinymce

i have a tinymce editor instance and by default the tooltips are positioned to the south of the object (buttons menuitems etc)

i would like to position them to the right (or east)

i can see in the css for the tooltips that there appear to be classes that operate this behaviour, but i simply can not work out how to use them

default css snippet

```
.mce-tooltip-arrow{top:0;left:50%;margin-left:-5px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-top:none;border-left-color:transparent;border-right-color:transparent}.mce-tooltip-nw .mce-tooltip-arrow{top:0;left:10px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-top:none;border-left-color:transparent;border-right-color:transparent}.mce-tooltip-ne .mce-tooltip-arrow{top:0;right:10px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-top:none;border-left-color:transparent;border-right-color:transparent}.mce-tooltip-s .mce-tooltip-arrow{bottom:0;left:50%;margin-left:-5px;border-top-style:solid;border-bottom:none;border-left-color:transparent;border-right-color:transparent}.mce-tooltip-sw .mce-tooltip-arrow{bottom:0;left:10px;border-top-style:solid;border-bottom:none;border-left-color:transparent;border-right-color:transparent}.mce-tooltip-se .mce-tooltip-arrow{bottom:0;right:10px;border-top-style:solid;border-bottom:none;border-left-color:transparent;border-right-color:transparent}.mce-tooltip-e
```

can you see things like .mce-tooltip-**ne** in there - i assume that controls placing the tooltip to the north east

but i literally cant even make it happen

please help

Comment: if 'ne' positions the tooltip to north-east then try using that class for the tooltips, it will be helpful if you will provide the html code for the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i couldnt work out how to call the styles with the compass bearings

so i just shifted the tooltip using a couple of styles in the default tooltip class

highlighted in bold below

*.mce-tooltip{position:absolute;left:100px;padding:5px;opacity:.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);zoom:1}
.mce-tooltip-inner{ **position:relative;top:-10px;** font-size:11px;background-color:#000;color:#fff; **min-width:400;max-width:600px;** padding:5px 8px 4px 8px;text-align:center;white-space:normal}*

this is from /tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css

the additions to the code pushed the tooltip to the right enough for what needed

Comment: Code without styling lacks styling : (

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you are referring to the tooltip shown in image above, that is simply a native browser tooltip displaying the title attribute of the anchor tag containing the icon.

Here's the HTML for that button:

```
<a title="Bold (Ctrl+B)" 
   onclick="return false;"
   onmousedown="return false;"
   class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_bold"
   href="javascript:;" id="story_content_bold">
    <span class="mceIcon mce_bold"></span>
</a>
```

Based on the above, the short answer to your question is: no you cannot change the position of the browser's native tooltip.

However there may be ways to manipulate the way the tooltips are displayed, which will require you to make changes to tinyMCE source code.

One idea is to use another attribute to contain the title text. This way you can use CSS to style the tooltip based on the alternative attribute rather than having the native browser tooltip.

For example you can use data-alt attribute:

```
<a data-alt="Bold (Ctrl+B)" class="specialtooltip"></a>
```

Then use CSS to style it as tooltip:

```
a.specialtooltip[data-alt]:hover:after { 
    /* style to achieve tooltip effect */ 
}
```

Please refer to this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/va3jn2qy/1/